# How can i stop getting exceptions on my app service when I turn on Application Insights in Azure on a web app service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a app service in Azure, its a web app , asp.net v4.7.
When i turn on Application Insights , I keep getting the error,

```
Exception: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, 
Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any ideas on how can i stop this happening ?

Comment: Are you able to build and run your App locally ?

Comment: What do you want to do, fix the error or ignore the exception and prevent it from being logged?

Comment: want to fix this , because i need to enable app insights for monitoring. Otherwise whats the point of app insights ?

Answer (score 1):

To add Application Insights to the `ASP.Net 4.7.2`, please follow the below steps.

- Right click on the **`Project`** folder => **`Add`** => **`Application Insights Telemetry`** => Application Insights Sdk (Local) and complete the Next Steps.

[image]

- NuGet Packages related to `Application Insights` and `ApplicationInsights.config` will be added to the Project.
- In Azure Portal, Create the **`Application Insights`** and copy the **`ConnectionString`** and paste in the `ApplicationInsights.config` Connection String Section.

Deploy the Application and Turn on **`Application Insights`** in the Portal.

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

> The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe,
> Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

- Check whether updated version of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`  is added.

Make sure your `.csproj` folder contains the below Reference

```cs
 <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.3\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

To open `.csproj` file, right click on the Project folder and select `Unload Project`. Make sure to click again on  `Reload Project`.